# uWSGI webserver takes way too long to restart on prod

Tags: python, webserver, uwsgi

I have started using uWSGI as a web server for my flask application.
I did this for a `seamless deploy (no down time)`
my uWSGI version is `uWSGI==2.0.10`

1. I simulated on localhost and restarted using ***kill -HUP `cat master.pid`*** and it restarts instantly.
2. On production it takes about a minute (which is a lot ) to start getting new requests after this message:

```
    Gracefully killing worker 8 (pid: 16498)...
        ...gracefully killing workers...
        Gracefully killing worker 1 (pid: 16491)...
        Gracefully killing worker 2 (pid: 16492)...
        .....
        Gracefully killing worker 7 (pid: 16497)...
        Gracefully killing worker 8 (pid: 16498)...
```

Comment: It seems that the workers are in a busy state to they will take their time to finish some requests first. The load pattern on production is presumably different than on development.

Answer (score 0):

Graceful reloads imply workers cooperation, they get signal HUP and they need to die into 60 seconds.

There are various reason to block the procedure:

- you have overridden the HUP signal handler
- your workers generate non daemon threads
- a bug in your app is preventing the worker to correctly end
- ...

You could investigate about why your workers are blocked (eventually strace them) or simply be less "merciful", decreasing (via `--worker-reload-mercy` option) those 60 seconds to a lower value

Comment: any idea why is this happening in prod and not in developement?